# Magento - API not being updated

Tags: php, magento

The previous provider killed several kittens by changing the core many times of a Magento 1.6.2.0 distribution.

So, in order to solve an issue in record time, we had to screw and hit the kittens' corspses: we still maintain the modified API: `catalog_category.assignProduct`.

So far, we have this API for the method:

```
public function assignProduct($categoryId, $productId, $position = null, $identifierType = null)
{
    $datos = explode('|', $categoryId);
    $productId = array_shift($datos);
    $categorias_actuales = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                           ->getCollection()
                           ->addIsActiveFilter()
                           ->addIdFilter($datos)
                           ->addLevelFilter(3)
                           ->getAllIds();
    $incat = function($cat) use ($categorias_actuales) {
        return in_array($cat, $categorias_actuales);
    };

    $result = array_combine($datos, array_map($incat, $datos));

    try {
        $product = Mage::helper('catalog/product')->getProduct($productId, null, $identifierType);
        $product->setCategoryIds($categorias_actuales);
        $product->save();
    } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('data_invalid', $e->getMessage());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $this->_fault('internal_error', $e->getMessage());
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The intention of the API was to assign many categories at once for a product. However this is a modified version because the previous was prohibitively slow. And the curious fact is that **this worked until recently**. It's intention was to:

1. only the first parameter is used, and instead of an integer value, a kitten was killed here and the API now expects a string like `"productId|catgId1|catgId2|cargId3|..."` where the first value is a product id and the second to last values are categories ids; each of them being integer values. The parameter is broken by pipe character ("|") and the product id is popped. In this way, we have the product id in one var, and the categories array in another var.
2. get the categories collection keeping only the active ones in level 3 (i.e. depth for the category in the tree) whose ids are among the specified ones. This means: if provided categories are array(3, 5, 7, 8) (e.g. from a "245|3|5|7|8" parameter, being "245" the product id) and one of them does not exist or is not active (e.g. 7 is not active and 8 does not exist), the returned value in `$categorias_actuales` is [3, 5].
3. as for debugging porpuse, map each input category to existence and validity. this means: existent&&active&&level=3 categories will have "true" as value, while non-existent or non-active categories will have "false" as value. For the given example, the returned array would be: array(3 => true, 5 => true, 7 => false, 8 => false), since 7 is not active and 8 does not exist.
4. in the try-catch block: a. retrieve the product; b. set the filtered ids (in the example: [3, 5]) as product categories in the just-fetched product; c. save the product.

However, I have the following **issues**:

1. The function returns true, so returning $result would not give me the array $results as return value (my intention was to know in which categories was the product actually inserted).
2. Changing to `false` instead of `$result` in the return statement had no effect at all: the obtained/displayed value from the API call was still `true`.
3. Throwing a `new Exception("something's going on here")` had no effect at all. Still `true` at output.
4. `dying` (`die('something's going on here')`) neither had effect. Still seeing (guess what?) `true` at the output.
5. **Edit**: Also tried a syntax error!! (guess what? nothing happens).

It's not only that I tried these steps, but also refreshed the cache (System > Cache Management > select all and refresh, and even clicking the "Flush Magento Cache" button).

**Questions**:
 1. given the **issues** before: how can I debug that API call?
 2. what could be causing the product not being saved with their categories? By calling category.level I can see that the given ids (i.e. given in the first parameter to category.assignProduct) exist.

I'm a n00b @ magento API and perhaps I'm missing something usually obvious. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you disable compilation? You can do it in one of these two ways.

1. `System -> Tools -> Compilation` in admin
2. Use SSH/shell and navigate to your magento root. Do the following commands:

   - `cd shell`
   - `php -f compiler.php disable`

Also, if your web server runs PHP APC with `apc.stat` set to `0` (you can check this by running `php -i | grep apc.stat` or looking for it at any `phpinfo()` output), please restart your `apache2` web server or if you use `php5-fpm` --  restart that one, too.

Then, if all else fails, try looking for an equivalent file at `app/code/local`.

e.g. if your file is somewhere in `app/code/core/Mage/Path/ToApiFile.php`, look for the local version at `app/code/local/Mage/Path/ToApiFile.php`.

Finally, a very useful shell command for searching code instances:

```
$ cd app/code/ 
$ grep -rin "function assignProduct" *
```

Comment: Compilation!! I'll try it now. I forgot that step.

Comment: Awesome. Everybody forgets compilation -- it's just effing impossible to remember at times.

Comment: Also, stop killing kittens plz. Move your core edits to a module or something :D

Comment: I didn't kill them. The former provider killed them, and I had to solve a problem in record-time. I hate killing kittens, but have no budget-time to fix the whole crap (which has more dead kittens that I mentioned about) and move everything to a new module (and I'm too n00b to do that quickly) - actually my fix was minor and other ppl will maintain the code, so wouldn't be convenient to move everything to a new side, where they will perhaps no find the fix.

Comment: Every minute a core code edit persists, a kitten dies. :( RIP 1293710273 kittens. Anyway, good luck with your endeavor, dude! I know the feeling.